# Entity Framework some times not return results to List

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I have some problem with EF. So, i have 1000000 records in my mysql table. I need query  with limit. For example, i do query with skip 50000

```
var listRoutes = (from c in context.Routes
                          where c.Alias != ""
                          orderby c.Alias ascending 
                          select c).Skip(50000).Take(500).ToList();
```

and listRoutes has 500 records. If i do query with skip 100000

```
var listRoutes = (from c in context.Routes
                              where c.Alias != ""
                              orderby c.Alias ascending 
                              select c).Skip(100000).Take(500).ToList();
```

or

```
List<Route> listRoutes = context.Routes.Where(x => x.Alias != "").OrderBy(a => a.Alias).Skip(100000).Take(500).ToList();
```

listRoutes has 0 record. But, if i do query wiht skip 100000 or more by

```
List<Route> listRoutes = context.Database.SqlQuery<Route>("SELECT * FROM testcmsdatamap.routes WHERE alias != '' order by alias asc limit 500000, 500").ToList();
```

listRoutes has 500 too... What's problem?

Comment: Dont query too much record from database, 10k is enough, you loop to get all record u need. Dont get all at once

Comment: i don't get all records, i need skip 100k for example and take 500 records. But EF returns 0 record to list. But if i do that with SqlQuery, all works fine. Why that doesn't work with Linq and EF?

Comment: did you check the generated SQL?

Comment: yes, i inserted generated sql to mysql workbench and workbench returned results fine.

Comment: probably you are skipping more than what you have with ur second query.check ur actual record count

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is resolved. Problem was in timeout in big data. EF build wrong SQL. Simple SQL query was build for INDEX . So, i have other problem [Entity Framework with Mysql Index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13414464/entity-framework-with-mysql-index)