# Entity Framework with Mysql Index

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, mysql, entity-framework

EF generate SQL like SELECT blablabla WHERE @gp1 != `Extent1`.`Alias` ORDER BY `Extent1`.`Alias`, where alias is INDEX. But mysql requires a different argument positions in WHERE for index: WHERE `Extent1`.`Alias` != @gp1. So, how can i change argument position in EF or how can i apply FORCE INDEX in EF?

Answer (score 0):

http://vincentlauzon.wordpress.com/2011/04/21/entity-framework-4-1-bypassing-ef-query-mapping-8/

I believe you want to do something like that.